# jQuery dialog - submit form via ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, dialog

I'm displaying a large form with lots of validation in a jQuery dialog box, but I'm now wondering if there's anyway of getting it so that once I submit the actual form, it will load via Ajax and stay in the modal window I have open? Not sure if there's anyway of doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **MUST** check out this wonderful [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/)  for `ajaxifying` your forms. The beauty of it is that if you have put validations inside `pattern` attribute of your inputs (which I prefer to do rather than writing javascript snippets for every input field) the form will get submitted only when each of the validations passes. In short the default behavior of your submit event will change and you will have an exact replica of your `REQUEST`, except that this time it is in `ajax`.

Comment: I wanted to avoid an extension if possible but honestly this looks great, tempted but it'd mean re-doing my validation maybe, hm!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you must hyjack the submit button to perform an ajax GET passing it all the form fields, then return false;

Comment: button only takes care of part of it...what if user hits "enter"?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.mySubmitButton').bind('click', function(e) {
   //do something else
   return false; //stops form from submitting the normal way.
});
```

or

```
   $('form#IDofForm').submit(function() {
      //do something upon submit
   });
```

or a combo of both if you wish

Answer (score 1):

Here's a failry simple method that will just replace the form element itself upon submit success. I am using on() method so the code can run on page load prior to form being loaded in ajax

```
$(document).on('submit', '#formID',function() {
    var $form = $(this);
    var dataToServer = $form.serialize();
    $.post(urlString, dataToServer, function(dataFromServer) {
        /* run ajax sucess code here */

        $form.replaceWith(dataFromServer);


    });
    return false; /* avoid browser submitting form*/

});
```

EDIT: how you integrate this will depend on your validation methods also